# Datagrid using fuel ux

Tags: datagrid, fuelux

I'm using Fuel ux data grid for showing records in a table format. I need some additional functionality. I have to create a link button inside the data grid each row. Please anyone tell me is it possible? If yes let me know the solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible - Adam Alexander has some sample code here: https://github.com/adamalex/fuelux-dgdemo/blob/master/index.html#L129-134

The general process is to create a formatter function that can take the returned data from your data source and apply a transformation to create html, text, or other content as needed. Note that the column named 'image' doesn't reference anything that exists in the original data, but the property 'image' on item is created by the formatter function so it can be rendered.

The above code was used for this article, if you want to see it in action: http://dailyjs.com/2012/10/29/fuel-ux/